# Joining multiple tables to one table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a rather complex (well for me) sql query happening and I am having trouble with some concepts.

I have the following sql on a webpage that i am building

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[Enrolment].[_identity], [dbo].[Enrolment].CommencementDate, 
    [dbo].[Enrolment].CompletionDate, [dbo].[Enrolment].enrolmentDate, 
    [dbo].[Course].name coursename, [dbo].[Course].Identifier as QUALcode, 
    [dbo].[Person].givenName, [dbo].[Person].Surname,[dbo].[Employer].name as empname, 
    [dbo].[Employer].Address1,[dbo].[Employer].Suburb,[dbo].[Employer].Phone,
    [dbo].[Employer].PostCode,[dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].name as enrolname, 
    [dbo].[Student].identifier,[dbo].[Student].person,[dbo].[Contact].person as CONTACTid
FROM 
    (((([dbo].[Enrolment] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Course] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].course = [dbo].[Course].[_identity])
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Employer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].employer = [dbo].[Employer].[_identity]) 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].status = [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].[_identity])
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Student] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].student = [dbo].[Student].[_identity]) 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Person] ON [dbo].[Student].person = [dbo].[Person].[_identity] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Contact] ON [dbo].[Employer].[_identity] = [dbo].[Contact].employer 
WHERE 
    (([dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].name) = 'training' 
    OR
    ([dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].name) = 'enrolled')
```

This is working fine but what I would like to do is join to the `[dbo].[Person]` table again but this time joining from another table so the code I effectively need to patch into the above statement is

```
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Trainer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].Trainer = [dbo].[Trainer].[_identity])

LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Person] ON [dbo].[Trainer].person = [dbo].[Person].[_identity]
```

I then need to be able to get from the person table the name of the student and the name of the trainer, so I need 2 records from the person table for every record from the `Enrolment` table, the fields I need from the person table are the same for both trainer and student in that I am trying to get the `given name` and `surname` for both.

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could not get your question exactly, can you explain more,,, may be by some data

Comment: Drop all those unnecessary round brackets in your `FROM` and `JOIN` statements - makes things harder to read than it needs to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliasing like this..

```
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Trainer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].Trainer = [dbo].[Trainer].[_identity])
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS p ON [dbo].[Trainer].person = p.[_identity]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use replace your from clause with this. You have to just first use the Trainer table join, then Person table, then use the AND keyword to use multiple mapping with single table

```
FROM (((([dbo].[Enrolment] 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Course] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].course = [dbo].[Course].[_identity])
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Employer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].employer = [dbo].[Employer].[_identity]) 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].status = [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].[_identity])
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Student] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].student = [dbo].[Student].[_identity]) 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Trainer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].Trainer = [dbo].[Trainer].[_identity]) 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Person] ON [dbo].[Student].person = [dbo].[Person].[_identity] 
                            AND [dbo].[Trainer].person = [dbo].[Person].[_identity]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Contact] ON [dbo].[Employer].[_identity] = [dbo].[Contact].employer
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you all very much, I shall give this a try later on and let you all know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right - what you are trying to do is to join the same table twice in your SQL. You have one table `Person` which has both student and trainer information and you want to see their details side by side in your result set. So you need to join `Person` once with `Student` and another time with `Trainer`

To do this - you will have to join `Person` table together. Give your tables an alias like the other answers have suggested. Then your `FROM` clause can look like this -

```
FROM (((([dbo].[Enrolment] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Course] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].course = [dbo].[Course].[_identity])

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Employer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].employer = [dbo].[Employer].[_identity]) 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].status = [dbo].[EnrolmentStatus].[_identity])

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Student] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].student = [dbo].[Student].[_identity]) 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Person] P1 ON [dbo].[Student].person = P1.[_identity] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Contact] ON [dbo].[Employer].[_identity] = [dbo].[Contact].employer 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Trainer] ON [dbo].[Enrolment].Trainer = [dbo].[Trainer].[_identity])

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Person] P2 ON [dbo].[Trainer].person = P2.[_identity]
....
....
```

Here `P1` and `P2` are two aliases for [Person]